# Pivot table with multiple aggregate value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to pivot below table, is that possible?

But if I aggregate them by Code, Value A or B will be gone because of it.

From

| Name | Code | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | Code1 | A |
| Kevin | Code1 | B |
| Kevin | Code2 | C |
| Kevin | Code3 | D |
| Tom | Code1 | E |
| Tom | Code2 | F |
| Tom | Code3 | G |

To

| Name | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | A | C | D |
| Kevin | B | C | D |
| Tom | E | F | G |

Query I tried....

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max), @query AS NVARCHAR(max);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Code) 
FROM Table c
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'with mapping as 
             (SELECT 
                Name
                , ' + @cols + ' 
             from (select name
                       , Code
                       , Value
                    from Table) x
             pivot 
             (max(Code)
             for Name in (' + @cols + ')) p )' 

execute(@query)
```

Tried myself but I can only achieve below

| Name | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | A or B(depend on aggregated max or min) | C | D |
| Tom | E | F | G |

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say this is not the idea of the pivot function. Either Code1 is a value or a key - either you perform an aggregate on it or you use it in the same way you use the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fixed column list version. You should build your dynamic one using this template.

```
select Name 
  , first_value(Code1) over(partition by Name order by rn) Code1
  , first_value(Code2) over(partition by Name order by rn) Code2
  , first_value(Code3) over(partition by Name order by rn) Code3
from (
   select t.* , row_number() over(partition by Name, Code order by Value) rn
   from tbl t
   ) t
pivot (max(value) for code in (Code1, Code2, Code3)) p
order by Name;
```

Comment: I changed first_value function to max as first_value since not return each Value for the same Code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` and some arithmetic:

```
select name,
       max(case when code = 'Code1' then value end) as code1,
       max(case when code = 'Code2' then value end) as code2,
       max(case when code = 'Code3' then value end) as code3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, code order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name, seqnum;
```

It is not clear if the dynamic SQL is due to a dynamic number of columns or an attempt to solve this problem.  But this can be adapted for dynamic SQL as well.